# moving columns to new sheet excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a sheet with information in columns (approx 200) which I would like to move to new sheet. The idea is  that I need column A in each new sheet following with column B, then next sheet again column A + column C and so on till the last column. Could someone help me with this?

```
Sub copyColumns()
    
    Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A:B,D:D").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Columns("A:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Columns("C:C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A:B,D:D").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub

Comment: This is the code I have made so far using macros. The question is how do I make it so it does it automatically till the last column?

Comment: so you need approximately 200 new sheets?

Comment: Please, do not add code in comments like this. Edit your original question, make your post easy to read to get some help from Community.

Comment: Note the maximum number of worksheets in a workbook is 255. Anyway you should re-think if having that many sheets in a workbook can be practical at all. Please [edit] your question and include the purpose of all that. I think you are already up the wrong tree with your approach.

Comment: Note that you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66650352/edit) your question at any time.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I'm using Office 2019 and I can add many more sheets. Maybe you meant the maximum number of new sheets that you can add at once is 255.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Oh you are right, I somehow had in mind it was limited. But obviously according [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) it is just *"Limited by available memory"*. Thanks for correcting me. Still I see no point in having that many worksheets. Somehow looks like a wrong approach to me.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Columns

- The following will copy columns `A,B,C` then `A,B,D` then `A,B,E`... etc. each to a new worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyColumns()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    ' Define Last column.
    Dim sLast As Long
    sLast = sws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Add worksheets.
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 3 To sLast
        With wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            Union(sws.Columns("A:B"), sws.Columns(n)).Copy .Columns("A")
        End With
    Next n
    
    ' Delete columns.
    'sws.Columns(3).Resize(, sLast - 2).Delete (- 3 + 1 = - 2)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

- When adding (handling) so many worksheets you might want to be able to easily delete them if something goes wrong:

---

```
Sub deleteWorksheetsExcept()
    Const ProcName As String = "deleteWorksheetsExcept"
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim arr As Variant: ReDim arr(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n  As Long
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name ' add/remove exact names from the following list:
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3" ' worksheets to keep
        Case Else
            n = n + 1
            arr(n) = ws.Name
        End Select
    Next ws
    If n > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To n)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Worksheets(arr).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ColumnsCopy()

 Dim rngSrc as Range
 Set rngSrc=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main_sheet_name").UsedRange
 intMaxRows=rngSrc.Rows.Count
 intSheetsCnt=rngSrc.Columns.Count

 For shtNum = 3 To intSheetsCnt-1

 With Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

  rngSrc.Copy Destination:=[A1]
  ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(intMaxRows, shtNum)).EntireColumn.Delete

 End With
 Next shtNum
End Sub
```